# HTTP 200 on Styles.css (camel case) but HTTP 401 on styles.css (small cap)

Tags: iis

this is a weird one. I have a site deployed on a web server. (Win 2003, IIS 6)

For some reason, I can do an HTTP GET on a file if I specify it with "camel casing".. i.e. Styles.css, but I cannot get the same file using "small cap" i.e. styles.css

In the later case I get a 401.3 exception.

I know that 401.3 is a security issue but I'm confused because as far as I know ACL has nothing to do with case sensitivity.

What is even more weird is that I have (in the same folder) other files that I cannot GET (small cap or camel cap) and they have the exact same security settings.

Any ideas on what the issue could be?

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to a proxy server in front of my server. This box caches the files so it was not really hitting the IIS server all the time.

Thanks Micky for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your web log or possibly use Process Monitor to see what happens when that file is requested?

Comment: Yes I checked the log and there's a 401 when using "small case" and a 200 when I use "camel case"